# Add product in opportunity functionality

Tags: opportunity

Add product in opportunity. I want to create same functionality using custom visualforce page and classes. I have two object "MyProperty" and "PropertyPlant". I want to add multiple ProperyPlant in one MyProperty object is it possible ? and how ?

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can any code you have got? Is something not working as you expect?

Comment: Thanks for Reply Girbot. I haven't tried anything yet. I just need idea that how I can add multiples propertied in my parent object.